# org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When I try to run my tomcat server I got the following errors. can any one tell whats worng with the configuration which I made. I have placed the snapshots of pom.xml,web.xml and my servlet.xml 
    ## Error Log ##

```
WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mithun.service.EmployeeService com.mithun.controller.EmployeeController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mithun.dao.EmployeeDao com.mithun.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.mithun.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springconf-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mithun.service.EmployeeService com.mithun.controller.EmployeeController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mithun.dao.EmployeeDao com.mithun.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.mithun.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springconf-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mithun.dao.EmployeeDao com.mithun.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.mithun.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springconf-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mithun.dao.EmployeeDao com.mithun.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.mithun.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springconf-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.mithun.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springconf-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.mithun.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springconf-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/springconf-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 71 more
```

[image: Pom.xml]

[image: Pom.xml]

[image: pom.xml]

[image: pom.xml]

[image: pom.xml]

> Web.xml

[image: wEB.XML]

> springconf-servlet.xml

[image: springconf-servlet.xml]

[image: springconf-servlet.xml]

> EmployeeController.java

[image: EmployeeController.java]

> 

[image: Project]

[image: Project]

> Database.properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Exception clearly shows that exception is coming in employeeController.EmployeeService so check EmployeeService is annotated with @Service annotation.

Comment: If you are not using annotation then check in applicationContet that your bean definition is there or not.

Comment: I have added the snapshots of my spring configuration . kindly let me know where I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

sure that org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect is ok in the springconf-servlet.xml

Comment: I have added the snapshots of my spring configuration . kindly let me know where I did worng.

Comment: Can you tell me the version of your oracle db?  if it's 10g or 11g,you can config "hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" in the database.properties you didn't post.

Comment: its hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect